# 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'run' tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am using Windows 10 64bit and I have found problems when trying to install TensorFlow and after a lot of tries, I have created a new environment and installed python 3.7.3, and used the following commands

```
# conda create -n TensorFlow python=3.7.3
# conda activate TensorFlow
# conda install tensorflow
```

And at last, TensorFlow is installed.
When trying the following code

```
# add_two_numbers_via_TensorFlow.py

import tensorflow.compat.v1 as tf
# import tensorflow as tf

# get the two numbers to add from the command prompt
intNum1 = int(input("enter num 1: "))
intNum2 = int(input("enter num 2: "))

# establish two tensors, one for each input number
num1 = tf.Variable(intNum1)
num2 = tf.Variable(intNum2)

# establish graph
sum = tf.add(num1, num2)

# note that this shows information about sum, but does NOT evaluate anything yet
print("sum = " + str(sum))

# instantiate a global variables initializer
globalVarsInitializer = tf.global_variables_initializer()
# globalVarsInitializer = tf.compat.v1.global_variables_initializer()
#globalVarsInitializer = tf.global_variables_initializer()

# finally we can run the graph (in a session)
with tf.Session() as sess:
    globalVarsInitializer.run()
    result = sum.eval()
# end with

# show the result
print("Result = " + str(result))
```

I have encountered the following

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-5-ba92b50d5523> in <module>
     25 # finally we can run the graph (in a session)
     26 with tf.Session() as sess:
---> 27     globalVarsInitializer.run()
     28     result = sum.eval()
     29 # end with

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'run'
```

Any help how to fix such a problem?

Answer (score 0):

** After this line `import tensorflow.compat.v1 as tf`, I used this line `tf.disable_eager_execution()`
** Instead of this line
`globalVarsInitializer.run()`
I used this line `sess.run(globalVarsInitializer)`

And that solved the problem.